# Is string message used inside System.out or Logger interned?

Tags: java

I have a webapp created using servlets where i have multiple log statements.

Assume LOG is a static variable of logger class initialised with proper context and class details, e is an exception cuaght..

Eg

```
  LOG.debug("some message here "+e.toString());
```

My question simply put, is the string portion "some message here " interned by default. Will statements like these cause lots of different strings to be created?

Will creating a final static string with the message "some message here " be more efficient or will it be the same if the string is indeed considered as interned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the string portion "some message here " interned by default.

Yes.

> Will statements like these cause lots of different strings to be created?

Yes: a new string is created to concatenate the literal and `e.toString()`; other new strings may be created to evaluate `e.toString()`, and to evaluate `LOG.debug(...)`.

Comment: Ok, any alternative? I get that the literal part will stay the same but the concatenation might create new strings if the exception message is different. I can't avoid printing the exception so is there any way to mitigate this issue?

Comment: @Kushan Alternative to what? There is no problem to solve. You have a new message to log: it gets logged; it gets GC'd.

Comment: @EJP thanks :) your edit cleared it up... There's no issue, it's just the way it is meant to work

Answer (score 1):

> My question simply put, is the string portion "some message here " interned by default.

*All* string literals are interned by default.

> Will statements like these cause lots of different strings to be created?

Not as far as the string literal is concerned. The concatenation creates new strings that are not interned.

> Will creating a final static string with the message "some message here " be more efficient

No.

> or will it be the same if the string is indeed considered as interned?

Yes. It *is* interned. No 'considered as' about it.

Comment: So do i need to have the final static approach or this is fine?

Comment: By final static approach i mean... Initialize the literal string as a member rather than using it inside the doPost and doGet etc..

Comment: It follows immediately from this answer that it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up for me. I was worried i might be landing myself in trouble by unnecessarily using up lots of memory due to duplicates

Comment: Well, you're probably creating unnecessary strings, if your log level is set higher than debug. Generally you should avoid concatenating the strings unless you know they're going to be logged. I don't know what logging class you're using, but most logging frameworks would let you defer the concatenation by providing a string like `"here is my message: {0}"`.